Nonvanishing matrix elements of electric dipole transition in $O_h$ symmetry from $E_g$-symmetric initial state to $T_{1u}$-symmetric final state
I am trying to work out Q6.3(b) of Dresselhaus's Group Theory: Application to the Physics of Condensed Matter. The question is to find the non-vanishing matrix elements for an electric dipole transition in full cubic $O_h$ symmetry from an initial state with $E_g$ symmetry to a final state with $T_{1u}$ symmetry. It is suggested to use as basis functions for the $E_g$ level the two partners $x^2+wy^2+w^2z^2$ and $x^2+w^2y^2+wz^2$, where $w=exp(2\pi i/3)$.
Below is the character table of $O_h$ group, where the superscript "+"/"-" denotes the even/odd parity under inversion.
$O_h$" />.
Since the electromagnetic interaction $H^\prime_{em}=-e/{mc} \times p\cdot A$ transforms like the momentum vecotr p, which corresponds to the irreducible representation $T_{1u}$ of group $O_h$. Based on the character table above, one can find that $E_g\bigotimes T_{1u}=T_{1u} + T_{2u}$. With this direct product result, I would expect that I would be able to decompose $H^\prime_{em}(x^2+wy^2+x^2z^2)$ and $H^\prime_{em}(x^2+w^2y^2+wz^2)$ into a linear combination of the basis functions of $T_{1u}$ and $T_{2u}$. I tried to decompose $p_x(x^2+wy^2+x^2z^2)$, but just ended up with $p_x \times [(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(w-1)(y^2-w^2z^2)]$. The first term $p_x\times (x^2+y^2+z^2)$ looks like transforming as $T_{1u}$ but the second term $p_x \times (w-1)(y^2-w^2z^2)$ does not seem to transform as $T_{2u}$. I appreciate it if anyone could help me out with this puzzle.
